# Einstein-Cartan Theory with modern Cartan structural equations?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, spinors, modified-gravity

I cannot find real derivations and analysis of the [Einstein-Cartan Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Cartan_theory).
This can probably be a neat up-climb to a Cartan structural summit, or very close.

I am not asking this because I want it quantum. The naturalness and the easy way to have no singularities because the space time field itself yields to finite stress just due to asymmetry in the tensors is what's interesting. The Cartan theory makes the difference clear, so it is appealing.

Worm whole to the new space time instead of singularities. Much better.

Anyone has suggestions?

- I do really mean arriving at the structural equations and the properties of the spin connection.

Comment: What about chapter 7 of Freedman and Van Proeyen "Supergravity" ?

Comment: OK for as long as there is no super symmetry to learn. Quantum fields is enough. There are no super partners. I'm happy with the classical fields now as you probably figured :D

Comment: @NormalsNotFar Table of contents look good expect Yang Mills. I don't consider that classical. :).

Comment: They approach it using tools only from Differential Geometry, field theory is not necessary.

Comment: Wait They use Poincaré as a gauge symmetry? That makes more sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/620427/2451